# Understand how to use a directive within a directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have created a small directive:

HTML:

```
<my-directive attr1="{{ data1 }}" attr2="{{ data2 }}"></my-directive>
```

Directive:

```
app.directive('myDirective', ['$rootScope',
function ($rootScope) {

    return {
    restrict: 'E',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        // do something...
    }
  };

}]);
```

Now I wish to add a plugin I found online: https://github.com/thenikso/angular-inview

And I wish to "do something" with my element only if that element is in viewport.

So I modified the directive like described in the in-view docs:

`<my-directive attr1="{{ data1 }}" attr2="{{ data2 }}" in-view="$inview">`

The problem is that I don't know how to get the `bool` that should be generated...

`attrs.inView` return a `string`: `"$inview"`.

I did several tests but nothing worked for me.

How can I add it properly and let it work properly?

That directive is within a `ng-repeat`.

Thanks

**EDIT:**

```
<my-directive attr1="{{ data1 }}" attr2="{{ data2 }}" scope1="someScope" in-view="checkStatus($inview)"></my-directive>
```

---

```
 return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
        scope1: '='
    },
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        // do something...
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to use a function and then process events passed by the inview directive.  Try something like below.

```
    app.directive('myDirective', ['$rootScope',
        function ($rootScope) {

            return {
                restrict: 'E',
                link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                    // do something...
                    scope.checkStatus = function(status) {
                        console.log(status);
                        if(status) {
// do something here
}
                    }
                }
            };

        }]);

<my-directive attr1="{{ data1 }}" attr2="{{ data2 }}" in-view="checkStatus($inView)"></my-directive>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What if I have to add some other scopes and use: ` scope: { myScope: '=', mySecondScope: '=' }`, how can I use in this case in-view? Sorry for extending my question.

Comment: What do you mean by scopes?  Variables?

Comment: I am sorry, but I am still not sure what you really want.  You should never pass a whole scope through an attribute to start with, but I also don't understand your goal here :)

Comment: scope is an object that holds all of your controller, directive data.  Why would you want to pass that to a directive?

Comment: I'm still learning how to do stuff properly with directive. This directive take many parameters and I have to pass user coordinates and location coordinates. and if the directive is in viewport I wish to edit css of the element moving an arrow in direction of the location. Maybe I should pass everything trough attributes... but I'm not very sure about everything to be honest!

Comment: I edited code and put do something there.  So if the status is true you can use another function there.  If you want to pass in an object of attributes, just use one attribute, but pass in an object instead of variable.

Comment: Ok, using only attributes it is working fine. I will try now to get rid of it, thanks for your help.